# How Do I stop the undefined to stop popping up in a Grading Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a Grading Calculator and I was wondering something. I have this problem where whenever I input a number it comes out as "undefined". Please help.

```
    <script>
        function Calc() {
            var grade = document.getElementById("grade");
            var totalGrade = document.getElementById("totalGrade");
            var gradePercentage = eval(grade/totalGrade)*100;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradePercentage.value + "%";
        }
    </script>
    <input type = "text" id = "grade" style = "width:50" autocomplete = "off"> / <input type = "text" id = "totalGrade" style = "width:50" autocomplete = "off">
        <br> <br>
    <input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onClick = "Calc()">
    <p id = "result" name = "r1"> </p>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "comes out as undefined"? What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: I tried adding ```parseInt() infront of both of them, I've tried changing what it reads, but as soon as anything is calculated it shows "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- `document.getElementById("grade")` doesn't get the value of the input just the HTML node.
- NEVER USE `eval()` really bad things can happen.
- `parseInt()` will work if you've got the value of the inputs rather than the inputs themselves.
- `gradePercentage` has no `value` property, it's (supposed to be) a number.

```js
function Calc() {
    var grade = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade").value);
    var totalGrade = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalGrade").value);
    var gradePercentage = 100*grade/totalGrade;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradePercentage + "%";
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "grade" style = "width:50" autocomplete = "off"> / <input type = "text" id = "totalGrade" style = "width:50" autocomplete = "off">
<br> <br>
<input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onClick = "Calc()">
<p id = "result" name = "r1"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should note that `getElementById` always returns the node not the value inside. You have to get separately. [Fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/wxqjdLbr/)

```
var gradePercentage = (grade.value/totalGrade.value)*100;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradePercentage+ "%";
```

Comment: doing that just gave me ```NaN```

Comment: debug and check whether grade.value and totalGrade.value are number only

Comment: also remove `eval`. you dont need it

Comment: Also it would be better to set your input type to number as well as a default value to 0. `type = "number" value="0"`

Comment: I added parseInt() before both of the variables

```         var grade = document.getElementById("grade");
            var totalGrade = document.getElementById("totalGrade");

``` and it still is none

Comment: I think I'll be using the Fiddle from now on (I was using JS.do)

Comment: Could you add the fiddle as a snippet to your answer. Without reading the comments the answer doesn't work on it's own.

Comment: Don't worry someone said something better so I just said that was the answer.

Comment: @phuzi ffiddled it